где достать sid в вк при регистрации аккаунта?
Мучаюсь с этим вопросом уже 2 часа
и в куках поискал и пробовал всем чем можно заменить его он, вк требует именно sid
Понимаю что он генерируется где то на серверах вконтакте, но можно ли его как то получить?

"в куках поискал" в ответе на запрос при регистрации аккаунта  смотрели?
